# How to apply wrap text style in JSF datatable?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a data table in my application, I fix the columns `width` as `200`. If i print small line in `datatable` `column` means it prints correct format. If i print lengthy line in the `datatable` column means, it cant wrap it out. how can i `wrap` the `text` in data table column.

**Problem Description**
 [image]

Comment: @alexander: has nothing to do with jsf either then, and nothing with a datatable, all just 'table' then... so html and css. Why not added these tags. And the answer is explicitly about PrimeFaces, so the question was about a PrimeFaces datatable... imo bad editing of tags

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can control word wrapping by CSS `word-wrap` property. Inside tables, this only requires the `table-layout` property to be set to `fixed`, so that columns with a fixed width don't auto-expand when their content is larger.

E.g.

```
.fixed-size {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

and

```
<p:dataTable ... styleClass="fixed-size">
```

Comment: @BalusC, is there a way not to brake a word while wrapping ?

Answer (score 5):

The below worked for me in Chrome not in IE

```css
.preformatted {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```xml
<p:column>
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.txt}" styleClass="preformatted" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: if the above style is applied in column level i.e., '<p:column styleClass="preformatted">' then it works fine in both IE and Chrome

Answer (score 1):

My sollution is to apply *word-break* style to column. Just like:

```
                <p:column id="accountsMaskColumn"
                          headerText="#{msg['mr.settings.headers.accountMask']}"
                          filterBy="#{item.accountMask}"
                          sortBy="#{item.accountMask}"
                          style="word-break: break-word">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.accountMask}"/>
                </p:column>
```

Hope someone find this useful